# (Error C2678) Error: No operator "<<" matches these operands

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std

**please note: this has been asked before**

so I am trying speed to learn c++, since my clan have ddecided to start writing a game, but I have only done delphi, C#, java

Problem:

I have read through a few posts regarding this issue and as I understand I need to "overload the cout class" for use of the operator "<<" and ">>",

what is the reason for this, and isnt there a easier method for achieving this

the 2 operators (prob x) are giving the issue

```
// Custom.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;

        double input, out;
        string degtype;

        cin /*>> "What is the temperature: "*/ >> input;
        cin /*>> "Convert to [C]elsius or [F]ahrenheit?: " */ [(prob1)>>] degtype;

        if (degtype.compare("C") == 0 || degtype.compare("c") == 0)
        {
            out = (-32 - (input * 1.8)) + input;
            degtype = "Celcius";
        }
        else
            if (degtype.compare("F") == 0 || degtype.compare("f") == 0)
        {
            out = 32 + (input * 1.8);
            degtype = "Fahrenheit";
        }

            cout << "The " [(prob 2)<<] degtype << "value is " << out;


}
```

Comment: Short story: you need to `#include <string>`.

Comment: **please note: if this has been asked before, _don't post it again_!**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The reason of reposting is that the answers to the previous post do not solve the problem, I would like to know the reason for the error and why it happens!

Comment: @juanchopanza thank you, it solved the problem, why would it give the error with strings but not with chars?

Comment: What makes you think that you can't create a game in C# or Java?

Comment: `<iostrem>` contains the operators required for streaming built-in types to `std::cout`. It makes no promises about `std::string`. I think this is covered in the duplicates.

Comment: @user2699451: Yeah, they do. I wrote one of those answers. It's basically the same as the one I wrote below that you accepted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the reason for this

As already explained in the duplicates you admit exist, the reason is that you did not include the proper header that provides all the `string` functionality.

Half of it appeared to work by pure chance, because some *other* standard headers included little bits for you, in order to do their own work.

> and isnt there a easier method for achieving this

No. Really, this could not be easier:

```
#include <string>
```

Write that.

That's it.